# Is it possible to choose in which container does an Azure classic Virtual Image is stored?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In **Azure Resource Manager (ARM)** you can create a Virtual Image from a given VM with command [Save-AzureRmVMImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt619423.aspx). That command has this parameter:

> **-DestinationContainerName < String >**
>
> Specifies the name of a container. The virtual hard disks (VHDs) that
>   constitute the VMImage reside in the container that this parameter
>   specifies. If the VHDs are spread across multiple storage accounts,
>   this cmdlet creates one container that has this name in each storage
>   account.

But I am using **Classic Service Mode (ASM)** and the command [Save-AzureVMImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495108.aspx) doesn't have that parameter.

So my questions are:

- **Is it possible to indicate Azure where to store that VM Virtual Image?** Any workaround?
- Bonus question: **Where is that ASM VM Virtual Image stored?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to your 1st question** - It is not possible to specify where in classic VM Virtual Images.

**Answer to your 2nd question** - When you create a classic VM you select a storage account. **The images are stored in the same storage account as VM**. If you go to that Storage account -> containers-> vhds. you can see them.

If you have not specified any storage account while creating a VM, it will use an auto generated account.

If you want your image to go a specific storage account, you have to first create it and specify it while creating your VM.

Comment: You are right. VM Virtual Image is stored in the same Storage Account where you created VM. Not very convenient for me

Comment: I agree. I think that's why we see that as an improvement on ARM VMs.